# How to correctly reference Tailwind theme with Vue3 and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have a Vue3 project with Tailwind and Typescript, and can't get around the Typescript errors trying to reference Tailwind from the js/ts files.

*tailwind.config.ts*

```js
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import tailwindForms from '@tailwindcss/forms';
import preline from 'preline/plugin';
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

export default {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    'node_modules/preline/dist/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary-light': '#c5ddf2',
        'primary': '#2368a2',
        'primary-dark': '#1d3f5d',

        'positive-light': '#dcfce3',
        'positive': '#21ba45',
        'positive-dark': '#16652a',

        'danger-light': '#f9e5db',
        'danger': '#DE6B48',
        'danger-dark': '#a92f25',

        'info-light': '#e3f0fb',
        'info': '#88ccf1',
        'info-dark': '#165974',

        'warning-light': '#fcf3c9',
        'warning': '#f2c037',
        'warning-dark': '#733714',

        'light-grey': '#e7e7e7',
        'grey': '#6d6d6d',
        'dark-grey': '#4a4a4a',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Lato', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwindForms,
    preline,
  ],
} satisfies Config;
```

I then created a helper to generate the fullConfig, as per their [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script):

*helpers/tailwind.ts*

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from 'tailwind.config';

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);

export default fullConfig;
```

And here is my tsconfig:
*tsconfig.app.json*

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "auto-imports.d.ts", "tailwind.config.ts", "vendor.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I try to reference the tailwind helper, I see this error:
[image: error message]

I can console log the tailwind import and actually see my custom colors being merged into the `tailwind.theme.colors` object, however typescript thinks that they are still in `tailwind.theme.extend.colors`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, I've just extended the type that the tailwind helper returns to  get around this error. I'd love to see a better solution from someone though if you have one!

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from 'tailwind.config';

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);

export default fullConfig as typeof fullConfig & { theme: { colors: Record<string, string> } };
```